# Alignment issues with BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, alignment, boxlayout, preferredsize

I am making an application for which I am using a `BoxLayout`. As you can see in the following picture, when the title string is short, it's perfect. But as the string gets longer, the `JLabel` gets more and more misaligned.
[image]
Here's some code that is related to the problem:

```
JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
centerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(centerPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
frame.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
//...
JLabel l = new JLabel(/*...*/);
l.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER); //I tried removing and adding
                                                 //this but nothing changed
centerPanel.add(l);
```

Is there something obvious I am missing? Google isn't being helpful with this problem.

In case it's important, the country-label-progress-bar things are just `JPanel`s with `FlowLayout`s.

SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SSCCE {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        final JLabel[] titles = new JLabel[5];
        JPanel[] smallPanels = new JPanel[titles.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < smallPanels.length; i ++) {
            titles[i] = new JLabel(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "foo" : "bar");
            p.add(titles[i]);
            smallPanels[i] = new JPanel();
            smallPanels[i].add(new JLabel("foobar"));
            smallPanels[i].add(new JProgressBar());
            p.add(smallPanels[i]);
        }
        f.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        final JTextField tf = new JTextField("foobar");
        tf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                titles[2].setText(tf.getText());
                f.repaint();
            }
        });
        f.add(tf, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(600, 600);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

To operate the SSCCE, type something in the text field and press enter.

Comment: I guess there are some problems with the allignment.Check out this, hope it will help you http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#alignment

Comment: @Zara I did try that. Nothing happened

Comment: Okay actually in this link, they have discussed the same issue as you are having.

Comment: @Zara yes, but I tried it and nothing happened, as you can see in my last comment.

Comment: Consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) that we can examine, run, test, and modify, and then help solve. Also, consider using GridBagLayout instead of BoxLayout.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels okay, hang on

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ok done

Comment: 1+ for the SSCCE and to the two answers below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) accepting `Min`, `Max` and `PreferredSize`, childs could be resizable from `Min` to `MaxSize`
- [FlowLayou](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html)t accepting only `PreferredSize`, rest (`Min`, `MaxSize`) is ignored by this [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), childs aren't resizable
- these `XxxSize` are calculated from `PreferredSize` came from childs placed into container (`JPanel` in this case)
- (your question) for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about your issue

Comment: so... I should wrap the `JLabel`s in a `JPanel` with `FlowLayout`?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an updated version of your SSCCE with a GridBagLayout. Not sure of how you want components to resize when labels or frame size changes but it should not be too hard to manage this.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class SSCCE {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        Insets insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);
        GridBagConstraints gbc1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc1.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc1.insets = insets;
        GridBagConstraints gbc2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc2.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc2.insets = insets;
        GridBagConstraints gbc3 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc3.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc3.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc3.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc3.insets = insets;
        final JLabel[] titles = new JLabel[5];
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            titles[i] = new JLabel(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "foo" : "bar");
            p.add(titles[i], gbc1);
            p.add(new JLabel("foobar"), gbc2);
            JProgressBar progress = new JProgressBar();
            progress.setStringPainted(true);
            progress.setString(String.valueOf(random.nextInt(100)));
            p.add(progress, gbc3);
        }
        f.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        final JTextField tf = new JTextField("foobar");
        tf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                titles[2].setText(tf.getText());
                f.repaint();
            }
        });
        f.add(tf, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that will help too :)

Comment: @PicklishDoorknob this is reason why post an SSCCE, then 1. any suggestion will be about a few moments (+1 Guillaume Polet), 2. avoiding to any mess came from unknow code, 3. an alternative to GBC are SpringLayout, custom MigLayout or TableLayout